# Convert Numeric value like 177200 to 1772.00 in T-SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, I have a query that returns a value of 177200. I need this value represented as 1772.00 as the last 2 digits are past the decimal. The query below is adding .00 to the end of the full value. I have no experience in this type of SQL statement. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    STR(SUM(ActualPrice), 10, 2) AS Total, Department 
FROM  
    #DepartmentSalesData
GROUP BY 
    Department
```

Comment: Just divide the value with 100? or multiply with 0.01?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type you're looking for is called [`numeric`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(ActualPrice) / 100.0 AS numeric(18, 2)) AS Total, ...
FROM ...
```

You're passing in a precision (`18` in my example) and a scale `2` in my example, as requested by you.